# Should I pass an object property into an object method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn object-oriented javascript. Working with a simple method I want to do this:

```
var users = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    this.log = function(){
        console.log(this.url);
    }
}
var apiPoint = "https://www.zenconomy.se/api/admin/tracking?format=json"
var liveUsers = new users(apiPoint)
liveUsers.log()
```

However, I've learned that it's often a good idea to pass variables into functions when working with normal functions, in objects however, this seems a bit clunky.

```
var users = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    this.log = function(url){
        console.log(url);
    }
}
var apiPoint = "here is my url"
var liveUsers = new users(apiPoint)
liveUsers.log(liveUsers.url)
```

Both methods work. What are the pros and cons of the different approaches, assuming that users.log only ever need properties from inside the users-class.

Comment: in the second example you're strictly tied to the instance name ("liveUsers") in the parameter and the url property needs to be public while in the first example it could be private

Comment: *it's often a good idea to pass variables into functions* ?? That doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: I would say that the first one looks cleaner but the second one you immediatly see what exactly log() is logging (but that could also be a naming usue, logUrl would be better then)

Comment: From an OO point of view, you shouldn't rely on your clients (the code outside the `users` function here) doing what you expect.  If the `log` function should only be accessing class members to do it's job, don't use a parameter, and instead get hold of the information needed itself.  You may want to get a reference to `this` within the `users` function and use that.  ie `var self = this;` and within `log`, use `self.url` in case the value of `this` isn't what you're expecting at some point.

Comment: In the first example, you are passing url variable to object property, than displaying this property to console log. In second example, you are passing url variable to object property, but also passing this variable directly to new function. If you change `this.url` in the second example before passing it to function, `console.log` will display not-modified variable

Comment: Before proceeding further, I suggest repairing your semi-colon key, which is evidently broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just mentioned you are trying to learn OOP in javascript, but actually, consider the log function in your `user` object, if there is no users instance, no `log` method eigther. That's not the same concept according to OO in C++ or C#. In my opinion, `prototype` will best describe the oop, do as following:

```
var users = function(url){
    this.url = url;
}
users.prototype.log = function(){
    console.log(this.url);
}
```

in this way, `log` will not be in any instance of `users`, it exists in `__proto__` which is a reference of `prototype` in any instance. That means when you create instances, they share all the functions, same as C++ or C#. finally, you should never use the second sample in your post, that's not OO things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `log` to always print the object's URL, then of course you would not pass in the object's URL as a parameter, since `log` can get it itself.

If you want to log various properties of the object, I'd suggest making separate routines such as `logUrl` and `logBlah` for the individual cases.

If you want `log` to print some arbitrary value, then it goes without saying that you need to pass in the value.

If there is nothing about logging that relates to the object, then you can just have a logging routine independent of the object that logs whatever you pass it.